# Segmentation Fault com malloc()

Tags: c, memória, alocação

Em uma parte do meu programa preciso criar um vetor cheio de zeros do tamanho do intervalo digitado pelo usuário:

```
scanf("%ld %ld", &n1, &n2);
int *vetor; 
vetor = malloc((n2 - n1 + 1) * sizeof(long int));
for (long int k = 0; k <= n2; k++)
{
    vetor[k] = 0;
}
```

Porém, quando digito alguns intervalos, como 10 1000000, o programa dá *segmentation fault* logo de cara, o que pode ser?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Use o [`calloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) e seja feliz.

```
scanf("%ld %ld", &n1, &n2);
int *vetor = calloc(n2 - n1 + 1, sizeof(long int));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Calloc.c).

Quando for acessar o elementos do vetor não use o operador `<=`, usar apenas o `<`, como começa em 0, o último elemento é o tamanho - 1, igual você faz para contar 10 número começando do 0, você para no 9.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%ld %ld", &n1, &n2);
int *vetor;
vetor = malloc(abs(n2 - n1+1) * sizeof(long int));
for ( k = 0; k <= abs(n2-n1); k++)
{
    vetor[k]=0;
}
```

Penso que queria fazer desta forma, é preciso colocar o `abs()` porque se inserirmos `n1=100` e `n2=1` ia gerar um numero negativo, o que nao queremos, então usamos o modulo.

Outra maneira era usar a função `calloc` como já referiram, porem usando o modulo.

`int *vetor = calloc(abs(n2 - n1 + 1), sizeof(long int));`

Comment: Boa resposta, mas acho que deveria ter mais ênfase no erro de lógica do OP,  que colocou no "for" a condição "k <= n2" quando deveria ser "k < (n2 - n1 + 1)". Em C é mais idiomático usar "<" ao invés de "<=" quando se percorre um array. (Eu inclusive criaria uma variável de trabalho "int nElems = n2 - n1 + 1" para o código ficar mais claro).

Comment: Eu não percebi muito bem isso, já vi códigos a usar `<=` ou só `<` não deveríamos de ter flexibilidade para entendermos isso?

Comment: o problema é que o OP usou "k <= **n2**" quando deveria usar "k <= (**n2-n1**)" como você fez (descontando a melhoria do abs)...a questão do "<=" x "<" é que é mais comum usar "<" em C, nestas sitruações

Comment: @zentrunix ah sim correto, nem reparei que tinha usado o `k<=n2` isolado.